# Generalized central limit theorem

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limit-theorems

I am looking for a generalized central limit theorem for non-square integrable stationary sequences. More precisely I suspect that when $(X_j)_{j\geqslant 1}$ is a stationary sequence such that $X_i$ belongs to the domain of attraction of the $\alpha$-stable law then

$$n^{1/\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

converges as soon as the dependence of $X_i$ is not too strong (maybe some mixing condition).

Are there results of this sort known? Or maybe I am wrong and my conjecture is false.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2717 could interest you.

Comment: That's probably what I was looking for. Thx Davide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the most recent results in this area is

Katarzyna Bartkiewicz, Adam Jakubowski, Thomas Mikosch, Olivier Wintenberger, *Stable limits for sums of dependent infinite variance random variables*, Probability Theory and Related Fields 150, 3 (2011) 337-372

which is available [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2717).

It gives sufficient conditions on $(X_j)$ in order to ensure the convergence of partial sums divided by $a_n$, where the conditions involve $a_n$. It seems these ones involve $\alpha$-mixing coefficients. Work on $\phi$-mixing coefficient has been performed in

Thomas Mikosch, Daniel Straumann, *Stable limits of martingale transforms with application to the estimation of GARCH parameters*, Annals of Statistics 2006, Vol. 34, No. 1, 493-522,

which can be downloaded [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605613).